# Add leading zeros to 24-hour formatted date/time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have several hundred thousand rows in my database with date/time stored as:

```
5/1/2017 3:10
5/1/2017 9:47
5/1/2017 12:33
5/1/2017 16:02
```

I'm running queries against this database to find rows with dates between two input dates. The following query mostly works:

```
"SELECT * FROM `bdrs` WHERE `CallStartDateTime` BETWEEN '5/1/2017 00:00' AND '5/1/2017 24:59'"
```

BUT it completely skips date/times before noon that are missing that leading zero. Manually adding the leading zero like so:

```
5/1/2017 03:10
```

fixes the problem, but I'd like to do this with a query. Is this possible?

Comment: Mysql datatime column won't store in `5/1/2017 3:10`, It will be stored as `2017-01-05 03:10:00`.

Comment: The data is imported into the database with that format. When initially set up with a datetime type, the SQL import would wipe the date/time and set it as 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000, so we set the type as varchar.

Comment: You would need to shuffle the string (varchar) back to datetime compatible format then change the column type from varchar to datetime.